# BottomNavigationView : Load icon from url not working in slow internet

Tags: android, picasso, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to load menu item icon of BottomNavigationView from url. I used Picasso Library for loading image.

```
    navigationView = (BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);
    disableShiftMode(navigationView);

    Menu menu = navigationView.getMenu();



 int i=0;
        for(BottomNavigationItem bottomNavigationItem : bottomNavigationItemList){
         i(i<5){
            final MenuItem navigationMenuItem = menu.getItem(i);

            navigationMenuItem.setTitle(bottomNavigationItem.Name);
            String icon_url = bottomNavigationItem.IconUrl;

            final Target mTarget = new Target() {
                @Override
                public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom loadedFrom) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapLoaded");
                    BitmapDrawable mBitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
                    navigationMenuItem.setIcon(mBitmapDrawable);
                }

                @Override
                public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable drawable) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onBitmapFailed");
                }

                @Override
                public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable drawable) {
                    Log.d("DEBUG", "onPrepareLoad");
                }
            };
            Picasso.with(this).load(icon_url).into(mTarget);
           }
            i +=1;
        }
```

With
slow internet :
[image]

With high speed Internet: [image]

How to ensure all icons are loaded?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **.placeholder()** in the picasso call, to show a custom image while the url image is loading.

Something like this:

`Picasso.with(this)
       .load(icon_url)
       .placeholder(R.drawable.image_name)
       .into(mTarget);`

Comment: I tried placeholder. But In the case of slow internet , it loaded only 1 or 2 icon images from url.